# How to add resource policy to existing S3 bucket with CDK in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm working on adding resource policy document to S3 bucket.

It works fine when I create a new Bucket:

```js
const newbucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'newBucket', {
      websiteIndexDocument : 'index.html',
      bucketName : 'NewBucket'
});

newbucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect : iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ['s3:*'],
      resources: [newbucket.arnForObjects('*')],
      principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal],
    }));

newbucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect : iam.Effect.DENY,
      actions: ['s3:*'],
      resources: [newbucket.arnForObjects('*')],
      principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal],
      conditions : {
        'NotIpAddress' : {
          'aws:SourceIp' : '***.***.***.***'
        }
      }
    }));
```

But if I try to get a bucket that already exists and add policy document it doesn't work:

```js
const existingbucket = Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'ImportedBucket',{
      bucketName :'ExistingBucket'
    })

existingbucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect : iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ['s3:*'],
      resources: [existingbucket.arnForObjects('*')],
      principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal],
    }));
```

Resource Policy document won't be added.

Furthermore this code deletes existing policy document and make it blank.

Anyone have experience or solution about this issue?

Comment: Does your CDK stack have permission to modify existing buckets?

Comment: I had similar issue, please refer [60905976](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905976/cloudfront-give-access-denied-response-created-through-aws-cdk-python-for-s3-buc) for the solution

Comment: Might be of help - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6548

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeah,its possible and i did it using the python cdk. There's a work around here. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6548
The CfnBucketPolicy was used there.

```
existing_bucket=s3.Bucket.from_bucket_attributes(self, 'ImportedBucket', 
            bucket_arn="arn:aws:s3:::bucket"       
        )

        bucket_policy=iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=["s3:Get*", "s3:List*"],
            resources=[existing_bucket.arn_for_objects('*')],
            principals=[iam.AccountRootPrincipal()]
        )

        s3.CfnBucketPolicy(self, 'bucketpolicy',
            bucket=existing_bucket.bucket_name,
            policy_document=iam.PolicyDocument(statements=[bucket_policy])
        )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This says, ``The bucket policy already exists on bucket ``

Answer (score 3):

I'm grappling with the same issue. After digging around I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#permissions), which implies it's just not possible with the CDK:

[image]

As a workaround what I'm planning to do is to output the exact AWS S3 command that needs to be run from the command line in order to append the S3 bucket resource policy. This way the user that deploys the stack (I'm using [server stack](https://docs.serverless-stack.com/)) knows of this additional manual step. Hopefully the AWS CLI supports

**Update**: Found a way to do this programmatrically, using a GET/SET approach on the bucket policy. The below is a [Node.js zx script](https://github.com/google/zx):

```
#!/usr/bin/env zx

const fs = require('fs')

...

async function updateBucketPolicy ({
                                                     awsProfile,
                                                     bucket,
                                                     lambdaOneRoleArn: lambdaOneRoleArn,
                                                     lambdaTwoRoleArn: lambdaTwoRoleArn
                                                   }) {
  const policyTmpl = '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"[LAMBDA_ONE_ROLE_ARN]"},"Action":"s3:PutObject","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET]/*"},{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"[LAMBDA_TWO_ROLE_ARN]"},"Action":"s3:GetObject","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET]/*"},{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"[LAMBDA_TWO_ROLE_ARN]"},"Action":"s3:ListBucket","Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET]"}]}'
  const policyAmendments = JSON.parse(policyTmpl.replace(/\[BUCKET\]/g, bucket).replace(/\[LAMBDA_ONE_ROLE_ARN\]/g, lambdaOneRoleArn)
    .replace(/\[LAMBDA_TWO_ROLE_ARN\]/g, lambdaTwoRoleArn))

  // First get the current bucket policy
  await $`AWS_PROFILE=${awsProfile} aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket ${bucket} --output text > /tmp/policy.json`
  const currentBucketPolicy = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/tmp/policy.json'))

  // Now update it, and put it right back
  const newPolicy = currentBucketPolicy
  newPolicy.Statement = currentBucketPolicy.Statement.concat(policyAmendments.Statement)
  fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/new-policy.json', JSON.stringify(newPolicy))
  await $`AWS_PROFILE=${awsProfile} aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket ${bucket} --policy file:///tmp/new-policy.json`
  console.log(`Updated  bucket ${bucket} policy with ${JSON.stringify(newPolicy, null, ' ')}`)
}
```

This solution is even suggested by AWS in `aws s3api get-bucket-policy help` manual:

> Get and put a bucket policy
> The  following  example  shows how you can download an Amazon S3 bucket
> policy, make modifications to the file, and then use  put-bucket-policy
> to  apply the modified bucket policy.  To download the bucket policy to
> a file, you can run:

```
      aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --query Policy --output text > policy.json

   You can then modify the policy.json file as needed.   Finally  you  can
   apply this modified policy back to the S3 bucket by running:

      aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --policy file://policy.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot modify the policy of an existing bucket through your CDK App. That is why it works perfectly when you create a new bucket.

If you need to make changes to that bucket's resource policy, I'm afraid you might need to do it manually.